# matplotlib animation movie: quality of movie decreasing with time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a movie with the `animation.FuncAnimation` function in matplotlib. The movie looks fine interactively, but when I save it with the command

```
anim2.save('somefilm.mp4',codec='mpeg4', fps=15)
```

It starts out fine, but then becomes blurry (both using QuickTime and vlc, so I figured it's the movie, not the player).

I've played around with *blitting*, since I thought it was maybe the fact that the canvas wasn't redrawn, but to no avail. Increasing the bitrate also doesn't help.

Setting `dpi=500` does improve the quality of the movie somewhat, though then it gets stuck repeatedly, which makes it difficult to watch.

I was just wondering whether this is the best one can do, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to dig into this problem it is important to understand that video files are usually compressed with a highly lossy compression whereas the interactive display is not compressed. The usual movie compressions are often extremely bad with graphs, and it is a matter of compression parameters.

There are four things you can do:

- set the image resolution (by `dpi`), but this may actually make the output visually poorer, as the problem is usually not in the lacking pixels
- set the image bitrate (by `bitrate`); the higher your bitrate, the better your movie will be - one possibility is to set `bitrate=-1` and let `matplotlib` choose the best bitrate
- change the codec (e.g., to `codec="libx264"`)
- give extra arguments to the codec (e.g., `extra_args=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p']`)

Unfortunately, these options really depend on the video codec, which is a third-party program (usually `ffmpeg`), the intended use of your video, and your platform. I would start by adding the kwarg `bitrate=-1` to see if it improves things.

If you cannot make it work, please add a full (but as simple as possible) example of how to create a bad file. Then it is easier to debug!

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation - I've tried to test it to some extent and the *codec* was what made most of the difference (while also reducing the size of the file). Somehow it doesn't work on QuickTime, but it runs perfectly with vlc. Setting `bitrate=-1` as the only modification to my original line didn't help, nor did only adding the extra args.

Comment: I added the `codec="libx264"` to my animation.save function to solve the issue. (Windows 10, ffmpeg)

Comment: setting to bitrate = -1 solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem while animating ~3500 frames of some subsurface water current vectors over a basemap and finally fixed the problem. I had been trying to set the bitrate in the `anim.save` declaration but was still getting the same blurriness later in the animation. What I had to do was set the bitrate when defining the writer:

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
writer=animation.FFMpegWriter(bitrate=500)
anim.save('T:/baysestuaries/USERS/TSansom/Tiltmeters/testdeployment/tilt2.mp4',
          writer=writer,fps=8)
```

If I set the bitrate to anything less than 500 the animation would still get blurry. `bitrate=-1` and `codec='libx264'` did nothing for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Another method that I recently figured out is to use `writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter()` instead. This saves each one of the frames to the disk and then stitches them together at the end. The problem is that with more complex animations, the bitrate needs to be set very high (up to 5000+) which makes the files very large (150Mb for a 2 minute animation). Not good for sharing! This method is slower but more storage efficient and there's no need to mess with the bitrate unless you really want to.