# Pixelated animations in Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, scipy

I've been using Matplotlib's animation facility to produce animated figures. I've noticed a problem which is particularly noticeable for animations with a large number of frames, which is that the quality of the figures deteriorates very quickly resulting in pixelated - blurry looking output.

Examples:

*Messy grid lines*
[image: Messy grid lines]

*pixelated output*
[image: pixilated output]

I've been rendering animations using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, ..., blit=False)
mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=15)
anim.save("path.mp4", writer=mywriter)
```

I've tried using blit=True/False but haven't noticed much difference.

Matplotlib version: 1.4.2. System: Mac 10.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib animation movie: quality of movie decreasing with time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203311/matplotlib-animation-movie-quality-of-movie-decreasing-with-time)

Comment: What is your default codec in `matplotlib.rcParams['animation.codec']`?

Comment: @Mr E, quite possibly a duplicate. I found that 'anim.save("path.mp4", writer=mywriter, codec="libx264", bitrate=-1, extra_args=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'])' resulted in the same outcome.

Comment: @aganders3 >>>u'mpeg4'

Comment: Have you tried to change the dpi in the `save` function?

Comment: @mrcl I have tried varying the dpi. The result, sadly, is higher resolution pixilation. The image is definitely better at higher resolution but the image is still quite bad.

Comment: I posted an answer showing what worked for me. Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

You can change the bitrate while creating the writer instance

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, ...)

FFMpegWriter = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
                comment='Movie support!')

# Change the video bitrate as you like and add some metadata.
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, bitrate=1000, metadata=metadata)
```

Then you can save your video.

```
anim.save("path.mp4", writer=mywriter)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you kindly for your solution mrcl, it would appear that manually specifying the bitrate does the trick. To anyone else dealing with this problem there is an auto mode (bitrate=-1), use of which results in messy pixilated simulations, if you want a nice result specify the bitrate manually, I have found that bitrate=5000 does the job for me leaving a pretty sharp result.