# How can I get rid of the compression artifacts in my matplotlib animation?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, compression, artifacts

I'm trying to create an animation in matplotlib and am seeing [compression artifacts](https://xkcd.com/2414/). The [static image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRftY.png) shows a smooth continuum of colors while the [animation shows compression artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibVTn.gif). How can I save an animation without these compression artifacts? I took some of the `writer` parameters from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209973/13337119), but they didn't solve the issue.

You can run the code in [this Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JY7KE5b5OJsgNyJRMjsyAPr3HECFCmXj?usp=sharing), or see it here:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

images = np.array([
  np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, 500), (50, 1)), 
  np.tile(np.linspace(1, 0, 500), (50, 1)), 
])
fps = 1

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
fig.add_axes(ax)
artists = [[ax.imshow(image, animated=True, cmap='jet')] for image in images]
anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, artists, interval=1000/fps, repeat_delay=1000)
writer = animation.PillowWriter(fps=fps, bitrate=500, codec="libx264", extra_args=['-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'])
anim.save('./test_animation.gif', writer=writer)
ax.imshow(images[0], animated=True, cmap='jet');
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You need to save to mpeg format instead of animated gif. Animated gif only supports 256 different colors for the whole animation.

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC. I'm getting a `KeyError` when I try to save it as an mpeg. It looks like using `FFMpegWriter` instead of `PillowWriter` solves the issue (even when saving as a gif), but I'm not able to use `FFMpegWriter` on Google Colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that produces a gif without artifacts and does so in Colab (in part thanks to @JohanC's comment).

First, I needed to save the animation using FFMpeg as an mp4 video. This creates a high quality video without compression artifacts.

```
writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=fps)
anim.save('./test_animation.mp4', writer=writer)
```

However, I wanted a gif, not a video, and I wanted to be able to do this in Google Colab. Running the following command converted the animation while avoiding the compression artifacts. (Some of these parameters are from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031).

```
!ffmpeg -i test_animation.mp4 -vf "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 test_animation.gif
```

I've updated the [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JY7KE5b5OJsgNyJRMjsyAPr3HECFCmXj?usp=sharing).