# saving mathplotlib animation to mp4 results in somewhat different video

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have created a regular animation using mathplotlib. here is the relevent line:

```
myAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_points_in_orbits, frames=np.arange(0, len(time_frames)),
                                  interval=3, blit=True, repeat=True, repeat_delay=1000)
```

The animation looks good in the preview:
[image]

However, when I save the animation to mp4 using this line:

```
myAnimation.save('first_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

There is some issue with the layers: the blue circle overrides the green dot. which should not happen because the blue circle is plotted before the animation and is not part of the animation at all. in the animation, only the locations of the dots are modified. Here is a screenshot from the mp4 video:

[image]

I have tried to play with the coded, bitrate and dpi as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203311/matplotlib-animation-movie-quality-of-movie-decreasing-with-time?answertab=trending#tab-top), but nothing seems to work.

**Edit:**

I could understand what causes the issue, though still not sure why this happens in the first place. Here is a simple code to produce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

TWO_PI_RANGE = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)


def draw_circle():

    x_array = np.sin(TWO_PI_RANGE)
    y_array = np.cos(TWO_PI_RANGE)

    plt.plot(x_array, y_array, 'blue')

def animate_points(i):
    g.set_data(np.sin(i), np.cos(i))
    return g,

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

g, = plt.plot([0], [0], "o", color='green', markersize=8)
draw_circle()

myAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_points, frames=TWO_PI_RANGE, interval=3, blit=True, repeat=True, repeat_delay=1000)

myAnimation.save('test.mp4', fps=60, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Now, if I put the `draw_circle` before `g, = plt.plot([0], [0], "o", color='green', markersize=8)`, the mp4 video looks fine (like the preview)

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. My question is very similar to the question I refer to. If this is because I didn't paste my entire code (which also the other question did not) - I don't think that this information is relevant and I preferred to make my question clear and concise. Arguably this is something with the codec issue and not related to the code to generate the animation itself.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. However, without an MWE, questions such as yours can be very hard to answer. Not every animation will result in errors such as the one you encountered. If someone wants to troubleshoot your problem now, they first have to work out the specific set of circumstances that give rise to this issue -- from scratch. That is a lot of work that you could prevent by doing a little bit more due diligence and providing a suitable MWE.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, added MWE and provided some insight. Though it appears I could solve the issue, I wonder what causes the issue; or probably I have bad practice using mathplotlib, I would like to be pointed out. Like should I plot the "dot" everytime in the animate function with the new location instead of using "set_data"

Comment: The root cause is probably the blitting. There is an [open issue on the matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2959) to that effect. See if your issue persists if you set `blit` to False.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, thanks. I tried setting `blit` to False. It made a difference in the preview which now matches the mp4 in the undesired outcome. So it appears the bug was not in the mp4, but rather in the preview. As I noted in my Question edit, I could solve this issue by plotting the green dot after the circle. And we can infer that `set_data` function does not move object to 'top' unless in the preview when `blit` is set to True -- which seems to be indeed a bug. Without this bug, I could have probably found the solution much earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the cause for the mismatch between the preview and the mp4 is a bug in the preview. Neither `set_data` function, nor the fact that an object is returned by the animate function, should cause the object to lose its zorder property and become on top. Hence in the given code that plots the blue circle after the green dot, we would expect the green dot to be behind the blue circle as presented in the mp4. This behavior should also be expected in the preview (`plt.show()`)

However, as @PaulBrodersen [brought to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72601580/saving-mathplotlib-animation-to-mp4-results-in-somewhat-different-video#comment128706844_72601580) there is an [open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2959) that the zorder of an object might be overridden if the object is returned from the animate function, *if `blit` is set to be True* (as in our example):

> In animated plots, the order in which artists are drawn is determined by their position in the sequence returned by the animation function, despite their own "zorder" property.

When `blit` is set to False, both the preview and the mp4 result in the same outcome.

Hence it was suggested that:

> With blitting the animated artists must be on top of all the other artists in the axes so we are already treating the animated artists differently.